# Time period to Instantaneous frequency

Tags: frequency-domain

I have simple smooth time signal with different time period. I would like to transfer period over the time to frequency, and to track frequency changing over the time, I would call it Instantaneous frequency?

PF-period frequency (1/T)... any suggestion?

[image: Time period to frequency]

Comment: This is called instantaneous frequency, yes. Is this your question?

Comment: This is how I called it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the instantaneous frequency of your data in Matlab as follows:

```
z = hilbert(x);
N = length(z);
f = angle(z(2:N).*conj(z(1:N-1)))/2/pi;
```

To get units of Hertz, multiply f by the sample rate.

---

There are other, similar estimators that do a similar thing. [This matlab code](https://sites.google.com/site/kootsoop/frequency-algorithms/wlp) can help.

Eric Jacobsen also has a couple of pages [here](http://www.ericjacobsen.org/fe.htm) and [here](http://www.ericjacobsen.org/fe2/fe2.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. John your suggestion I think giving good result, this is what I have been expected.

Original signal sampling frequeny is 102400 Hz and duration is 0.63999 seconds.

I did what Johns suggested in Matlab:

data = x; 
z = hilbert(x); 
N = length(z); 
fs=102400; f = angle(z(2:N).*conj(z(1:N-1)))/2/pi*102400; % to get units in Hz

After post processing I get x-axis- like 63999. How to get x axis in seconds like 0.63999?

Comment: t = [1:length(f)]/102400;plot(t,f);xlabel('Seconds');

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to create some sort of spectrogram. The only difference is that the spectrogram contains a full frequency spectrum for every time period, and you want to get just the dominant frequency, but you can run a dominant frequency search (maximum search), and you will get what you want. You have control both of the time and frequency resolution.